Ag grid react selectcelleditor handleChange method
I want to know onChange method for ag-grid-react in selectCell editor.
I am editing the cells, when I select option from name dropdown its respective designation options should come.
But this is happening when I am existing edit mode and starting edit again.
I want to happen it live, when I select name , respective designation should come in dropdown of designation, without exiting edit mode.
Any other solutions are as well welcome.
{
field:"name",
headerName:"Name"
cellEditorSelector : (params:any)=>{
          return {
            component: "agSelectCellEditor" ,
            params:{values:nameArr},

          }
        },
field:"designation",
headerName:"Designation"
cellEditorSelector : (params:any)=>{
          return {
            component: "agSelectCellEditor" ,
            params:{values:designationArr},

          }
        }

}

